# Printing all ASCII characters with index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, ascii

I'm trying to figure out how to print out all ASCII characters with index in Javascript. So far, I've been able to print out the actual characters, but not the index.
The code I've been using is:

> var s="";
>
> for(var i = 32; i < 127; i++) {
>
> console.log(String.fromCharCode(i));
>
> }

I need it to look like below

- 32:
- 33: !
- 34: "
- 35: #
- 36: $
- 37: %
- 38: &
- 39: '
- ...etc

Thanks!

Comment: Try `console.log(i + ": " + String.fromCharCode(i));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the index, just do `console.log(i)`.